# How to smooth a particular region of the object?

Tags: modeling

fairly new to blender. After I added modifier property subdivision, there were glitches on my model. How can I resolve it? Also, there're open 'cut lines'. Does anyone have suggestions on removing them? They're not intended to be there.[image]

Comment: Check the "clipping" box on your mirror modifier, then select the whole mesh in edit mode (A) then press M (merge) and select "by distance". The "gaps may be a little large to get by the default merge distance though - you can adjust the distance from the _operator panel_ (the little options box that pops up in the bottom left after you perform certain actions). I don't recommend changing the distance using the arrows, however, as it "steps up" too much for each increment. Instead, change the last (or second last) digit manually, until the gaps are removed.

Comment: You may also want/need to correct the normals after the merge as well - select the whole mesh in edit mode again and pick `mesh > normals > recalculate outside` from the menu at the top of the viewport.